# Swift4 : substring(from:)' is deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift4, xcode9

I recently convert my Swift3 project into the new Swift4, and I got some warnings:

```
'substring(from:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript with a 
partial range from' operator.
```

Here is my code:

```
let index = row.index(row.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let substring = row.substring(from : index)
```

Could someone give me a clean solution for this warning?

Thank you!

Comment: try with `String(row.substring.suffix(index))`

Comment: This is not a duplicate, other thread is about `substring(to:)`.

Comment: This is not duplicate. The mechanism of slicing subscript with partial range for 'for' is different from the 'to'